# EWS - Find last calendar modifications in Exchange Web Services 2007

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm new user of EWS web services and could handled different functionnalities to make them work(FindItem, FindFolder,getItem, etc...)
But I could not resolve this one:
I try to find all latest modification or creation of appointments in a calendar folder. 
My first idea was to create a FindItemType request with restriction on LastModificationDate extended field( PropertyId = 0x3008) and call the findItem method.

I've tried the following code, but result is always empty ( aorit.Items == null):

```
_esb = new ExchangeServiceBinding();
_esb.Url = serviceUrl;
_esb.Credentials = new NetworkCredential
{                
    UserName = userName,
    Password = password,
    Domain = domain
};

// snipped...

FindItemType fit = new FindItemType
{
    ItemShape = new ItemResponseShapeType
    {
        BaseShape = DefaultShapeNamesType.IdOnly
    },
    ParentFolderIds = folderTypes,
    Traversal = ItemQueryTraversalType.Shallow,
    Restriction = new RestrictionType
    {
        Item = new IsGreaterThanOrEqualToType
        {
            FieldURIOrConstant = new FieldURIOrConstantType
            {
                Item = new ConstantValueType { Value = lastModifiedDateSearched.ToUniversalTime().ToString("u") }
            },
            Item = new PathToExtendedFieldType
            {
                DistinguishedPropertySetIdSpecified = true,
                DistinguishedPropertySetId = DistinguishedPropertySetType.Appointment,
                PropertyType = MapiPropertyTypeType.SystemTime,
                PropertyId = 0x3008,
                PropertyIdSpecified = true,
            }
        }
    }
};

FindItemResponseType response = _esb.FindItem(fit);

List<ItemIdType> res = new List<ItemIdType>();
foreach (FindItemResponseMessageType firmt in     response.ResponseMessages.Items.Where(c => c.IsNotNull()))
{
    if (firmt.RootFolder.IsNotNull())
    {
        ArrayOfRealItemsType aorit = firmt.RootFolder.Item as ArrayOfRealItemsType;
        if (aorit != null && aorit.Items.IsNotNull())
        {
            foreach (ItemType item in aorit.Items)
            {
                if (item.ItemId.IsNotNull())
                {
                    res.Add(item.ItemId);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anybody knows if my query seems correct? Do I use the right way to do this?
Thank's for your help.

Answer (score 2):

After digging and digging, and... I finally found the problem. The PathToExtendedFieldType was not declared correctly. Should have been simply:

```
new PathToExtendedFieldType
{
    PropertyType = MapiPropertyTypeType.SystemTime,
    PropertyTag = "0x3008"
}
```